# MS Unit test Data Source cannot be found in test configuration settings

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I've a data source details defined in app.config file in a test project, but when I used the data source name in a test function it's not executing it rather throwing error like **"Data source 'MyDataSourceName' cannot be found in test configuration settings"**.

**Exception:**

[image]

**My Data Source in app.config file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="UnitTestConfiguration" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestConfigurationSection, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataSourceConnection" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DataSource;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited'"
  providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <UnitTestConfiguration>
    <dataSources>
      <add name="TargetDataSource" connectionString="DataSourceConnection" dataTableName="UserData#CSV" dataAccessMethod="Sequential"/>
    </dataSources>
  </UnitTestConfiguration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

**My test function:**

```
[DataSource("TargetDataSource")]
        [TestMethod]        
        public void UserValidationTest()
        {
}
```

Comment: Is your datasource present in data directory? I guess, that the database file itself should be marked as `DeploymentItem`You also should use relative paths to your data, according [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353086/microsoft-unit-tests-data-source-cannot-be-found-in-the-test-configuration-set)

Comment: Actually I'm thinking its pointing to the default test config file i.e. 'mstest.exe.config' from somewhere c:\programfiles\visual studio\IDE\... and that's why I'm getting this error. Is there any way that I can point to my project app.config file?

Comment: It's quite strange, maybe it happens, if you run the tests from command line. [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-using-a-configuration-file-to-define-a-data-source?view=vs-2017) shows how to add the settings to test project `app.config`